# Preventing \S in sed from matching tags (<p>, </p>)

Tags: bash, sed

Trying to make a customization script in bash:

```
GENDER=M
T='<p>He§She is a very handsome§beautiful man§woman</p>'
[[ $GENDER = M ]] && sed 's:§\S*::g' <<< "$T" || sed 's:\S*§::g' <<< "$T"

Output: <p>He is a very handsome man
Desired: <p>He is a very handsome man</p>
```

Likewise:

```
GENDER=F
T='<p>He§She is a very handsome§beautiful man§woman</p>'
[[ $GENDER = M ]] && sed 's:§\S*::g' <<< "$T" || sed 's:\S*§::g' <<< "$T"

Output: She is a very beautiful woman</p>
Desired: <p>She is a very beautiful woman</p>
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Note that `\s` and `\S` are PCRE-isms; they're not guaranteed to be supported by standard `sed`. Use POSIX character classes instead to be safe: `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]`, respectively.

Comment: Also, `foo && bar || baz` is **absolutely not** identical to `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`. Use the latter when in doubt.

Comment: Instead of nonspace characters, `[[:alnum:]]` might be a good choice to not match `<p>` and `</p>`

Comment: `[[:alnum:]]` has made the magic, thank you

Comment: (Pardon the title edit -- noticed this had attracted a downvote from somewhere; hoping having a more closely-fitting title will prevent more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `\S` is matching `<` and `>` characters when you don't want it to.

Switching from using `\S` to a POSIX character class not only makes your code compatible with more versions of `sed`, but also gives you control to add extra characters, in this case `<` and `>`, to the classes:

```
selectWords() {
  case $1 in
    M) sed 's:§[^[:space:]<>]*::g' <<<"$2" ;;
    *) sed 's:[^[:space:]<>]*§::g' <<<"$2" ;;
  esac
}

selectWords M '<p>He§She is a very handsome§beautiful man§woman</p>'
selectWords F '<p>He§She is a very handsome§beautiful man§woman</p>'
```

...[properly emits](https://ideone.com/Hd5QLo):

```
<p>He is a very handsome man</p>
<p>She is a very beautiful woman</p>
```

Comment: I can see your answer is much more complete but... Why not only substituting `\S` by `[[:alnum:]]`? Like @Daniel Farrell said above?

Comment: I'm not convinced that it's the right thing without a specification from the OP. Can they really never want to have different punctuation based on the gender selection? We really don't know enough to choose the right tool for the job, which is why I'm leaning towards the smallest change to their existing behavior (only changing how the specific characters we know are handled wrongly behave).

Comment: Oh, you _are_ the OP. Then, well, yeah -- you know best what you wrote the original code intending to do, and thus which possible fix hews closest to that intent. :)